# Redirect to facebook application after user login in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello i have an issue because i am new to create facebook application. 
I am using javascript sdk to create a basic application just for sending notifications to users.

I have the code bellow.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {

            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

            FB.api('/me', function(info) {
                $('#welcome').html("Hello there " + info.birthday );
            });

        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //User is logged into Facebook, but not your App
              var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
              oauth_url += '?client_id=xxxxxxxx'; //Your Client ID
              oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + 'https://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/'; //Send them here if they're not logged in
              oauth_url += '&scope=user_about_me,email,user_location,publish_actions,user_birthday,publish_stream';

              window.top.location = oauth_url;              
        } else {
            // User is not logged into Facebook at all
            window.top.location ='https://www.facebook.com/index.php';
        } //response.status
    }); //getLoginStatus
}; //fbAsyncInit
```

When the user is logged in and not authorized is going to authorize window and working.
When the user is logged in and authorized is working.
But when the user is not authorized and NOT LOGGED IN to facebook, the app is redirect me to the page to login the user, but after is not redirect to the app again to check if or not is authorized.

Can someone help me about this? how to do it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are making this way too hard for yourself. Use FB.login for the login process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1

But do NOT use it inside the (asynchronous) callback function of FB.getLoginStatus, it should always get called directly with user interaction.

Btw, `publish_stream` is deprecated since years and `publish_actions` covers the same permissions. No clue where you got that code from, but i highly suggest using the official Facebook docs instead.

Be careful with `publish_actions` though. It is not allowed to reuest read and write permissions at the same time. Only ask for publish_actions right before you need it - although, you do NOT need it for sending Notifications. See those links for more information about Notifications:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications
- http://blog.limesoda.com/2014/08/app-notifications-facebook-apps/

The second one is in german, but the code is the relevant part anyway. Make sure you read the whole article in the Facebook docs carefully, a lot of important information is in there.